# Отключить перенос блока на новую строку

Tags: html

потихоньку пытаюсь начать разбираться в html, не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы пятый и последующие блоки (один, два) оставались в своей строке, а также при сужении страницы, а не переносились на новую. Могу скинуть не тот код css, заранее извиняюсь :)

```
<div class="digital">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="digital-main">
            <h3> <span></span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="digital-top">
            <div class="col-md-3 digital-left">
                <div class="digital-one">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <label></label>
                    <p><sup></sup><sup></sup><sub></sub></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><p><span></span> </p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 digital-left">
                <div class="digital-one">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <label></label>
                    <p><sup></sup><sup></sup><sub></sub></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><p><span></span> </p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 digital-left">
                <div class="digital-one">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <label></label>
                    <p><sup></sup><sup></sup><sub></sub></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><p><span></span> </p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 digital-left">
                <div class="digital-one">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <label></label>
                    <p><sup></sup><sup></sup><sub></sub></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><p><span></span> </p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 digital-left">
                <div class="digital-one">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <label></label>
                    <p><sup></sup><sup></sup><sub></sub></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><p><span></span> </p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                        <li><p><span></span></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vm4fesL8/

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы используете bootstrap, тогда почитайте про [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid), возможно вашу проблему можно решить добавив к блокам классы вроде .col-sm-12, .col-sm-6 и тд.

Возможно вам потребуются [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) в сочетании с [:nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child). К примеру нужно чтобы на экране <= 992px шириной второй и третий блок были 50% ширины, тогда примерно так:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  /* Все блоки делаем на 100% ширины экрана */
  .digital-top .col-md-3 {
    width:100%;  
  }
  /* Второй и третий на 50% */
  .digital-top .col-md-3:nth-child(2),
  .digital-top .col-md-3:nth-child(3) {
    width: 50%;
  } 
}
```

Comment: ИМХО: Если человек использует Bootstrap не зная CSS, ему нужно читать не про Grid System, а про CSS..